# WebDriver. Exception при попытке найти элемент

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

**Тест**

```
public class test {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait myWaitVar ;


    @BeforeTest
    public void SetUpBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    }

    @Test
    public void login() {
        driver.get("http://trafficsland.com/user/login");

        WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-form-login"));
        emailField.clear();
        emailField.sendKeys("testUserSofia1");

        WebElement passField = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-form-password"));
        passField.clear();
        passField.sendKeys("NKj24s*(&^f");
        WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#.custom-button-submit"));
        loginButton.click();

        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-custom-open-menu")).isDisplayed());
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b) on port 8589
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0NMHHJA', ip: '192.168.0.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\VIKTOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir14388_11739}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=57.0.2987.98, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: a323dfaee9c742ec35ff306780c0c421
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#.custom-button-submit}

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:492)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at testTraficsland.test.login(test.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: @Andrew ответ как бы дан, и вопрос решен уже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
 "#.custom-button-submit"
```

Там либо `"#custom-button-submit"`
Либо `".custom-button-submit"`

```
# - ID

. - CLASSNAME
```

Comment: Да, заработал. Спасибо большое!